# Function getting firebase object returns hard to use object

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

### **What I am trying to do**

I am creating a social media app with react native and firebase. I am trying to call a function, and have that function return a list of posts from off of my server.

### **Problem**

Using the return method on a firebase query gives me a hard to use object array:

```
Array [

   Object {
   "-L2mDBZ6gqY6ANJD6rg1": Object {
      //...
     },
   },

]
```

I don't like how there is an object inside of an object, and the whole thing is very hard to work with. I created a list inside my app and named it items, and when pushing all of the values to that, I got a much easier to work with object:

```
Array [
Object {
 //...
   "key": "-L2mDBZ6gqY6ANJD6rg1",
  },
]
```

This object is also a lot nicer to use because the key is not the name of the object, but inside of it.

I would just return the array I made, but that returns as undefined.

### **My question**

In a function, how can I return an array I created using a firebase query? (to get the objects of an array)

### **My Code**

```
runQ(group){
var items = [];
//I am returning the entire firebase query...
return firebase.database().ref('posts/'+group).orderByKey().once ('value', (snap) => {
      snap.forEach ( (child) => {       
       items.push({
         //post contents
     });
     });
console.log(items)
//... but all I want to return is the items array. This returns undefined though.
})
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please let me know if I'm getting your question correctly. So, the `posts` table in database looks like this right now:

[image]

And you want to return these posts in this manner:

```
[
    {
        "key": "-L1ELDwqJqm17iBI4UZu",
        "message": "post 1"
    },
    {
        "key": "-L1ELOuuf9hOdydnI3HU",
        "message": "post 2"
    },
    {
        "key": "-L1ELqFi7X9lm6ssOd5d",
        "message": "post 3"
    },
    {
        "key": "-L1EMH-Co64-RAQ1-AvU",
        "message": "post 4"
    }
    ...
]
```

Is this correct? If so, here's what you're suppose to do:

```
var items = [];
firebase.database().ref('posts').orderByKey().once('value', (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((child) => {
        // 'key' might not be a part of the post, if you do want to
        // include the key as well, then use this code instead
        //
        // const post = child.val();
        // const key = child.key;
        // items.push({ ...post, key });
        //
        // Otherwise, the following line is enough
        items.push(child.val());
    });

    // Then, do something with the 'items' array here
})
    .catch(() => { });
```

Off the topics here: I see that you're using `firebase.database()....` to fetch posts from the database, are you using cloud functions or you're fetching those posts in your App, using users' devices to do so? If it's the latter, you probably would rather use cloud functions and pagination to fetch posts, mainly because of 2 reasons:

1. There might be too many posts to fetch at one time
2. This causes security issues, because you're allowing every device to connect to your database (you'd have to come up with real good security rules to keep your database safe)

Comment: where do I return items though? I need to return it back to the first function.

Comment: `firebase.database().ref(...).once('value')` is an async operation, meaning that the function `runQ` will be terminated before you actually get the results, you will get them, but the function has been terminated before that, therefore, you can't return the results back. What you can do is to use `redux` in your app, if you're willing to do that I'm glad to help. One thing though, since your app fetches posts from database, it's almost guaranteed that you need to use `redux`

Comment: So if I had a .then(()=>{}) that code wouldn't run?

Comment: No it will not, everything in `.then()` will be executed when the posts have been fetched, but `runQ` has terminated before that happens. Here's what you can do to test it, inside `.then()`, you `console.log('posts have been fetched')`, and at the end of `runQ`, you `console.log('The function is about to terminate')`, even though the second log statement appears after the first log statement in your function, the result is, however, the second log statement is executed first. One sentence: unfortunately you cannot just return the results back

Comment: Okay. Could I push the results to a state in a .then()?

Comment: Yes you can, simply use: `this.setState({ posts: items });` in `.then()`